# Why doesn't the null-coalescing operator work in this case?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to fetch record into listarray as follows:

```
List<Car> lst = new List<Car>();

string str = "select * from Inventory"; 

using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str,this.sqlcon))
{
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        lst.Add(new Car 
                    {
                        CarId = (int)rdr["CarId"],
                        Make = (string)(rdr["Make"] ?? ""),
                        Color= (string)(rdr["Color"] ?? ""),
                        PetName = (string)(rdr["PetName"] ?? "")

                    });
    }

    rdr.Close();
}
```

Make,color and petname may have null values and thus I used the `??` operator. I get the following error

> Unable to cast object of type system.dbnull' to 'system.string'.

What is the correct way of checking for null in this scenario?

Comment: @Code a great answer doesn't mean it can't be closed.

Answer (score 8):

`DBNull` isn't the same as `null`, so you can't use the `??` operator. You have to handle this case separately.

Replace:

```
Make = (string)(rdr["Make"] ?? ""),
```

with:

```
Make =  (rdr["Make"] == System.DBNull.Value ? "" : (string)rdr["Make"]),
```

Comment: System.DBNull throws compile error . Used dbnull.value instead and it worked fine. tx!

Comment: @Poongodi thank you i've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

`SqlDataReader` returns a DBNull object, which is not a C# null - it is an object representing a NULL value in the database.

You have a number of options, and creating a method to handle that might be most readable and save you on repeating code:

```
private static string GetStringOrEmpty(object dbValue){
    return dbValue == System.DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : (string)dbValue;
}
```

and then

```
Make = GetStringOrEmpty(rdr["Make"]),
```

Alternatively look into `Dapper` which is a very small but powerful ORM that will handle a lot of this stuff for you.

Comment: System.DBNull throws compile error . Used dbnull.value instead and it worked fine. tx!